# Is there anyway to view all the previous GIT reverts

Tags: git, github, version-control, revert, git-revert

I had reverted some changes done. Need to know the files and changes(diff) in the code that was reverted previously.

Comment: The revert commit has a default message which says 'Revert xxxx' and 'This reverts commit xxxx'. If you haven't changed it, you could use `git log --grep='Revert'` to list these commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just as ElpieKay said, you can use `git log --grep='Revert'`.

There is another default message “**This reverts commit** …”, so `git log --grep='revert'` or `git log --grep='reverts'` are also work.

If you want to show only one branch's revert log, you can use 
`git log branchName --grep='revert'`.

Comment: This partially works form me. This gives reverts that are not done by me(or my branch). As I'm new to git, can you please let me know if I can view reverts done only from my branch.

Comment: You mean not only the mybranch has revert log, but also other branch has revert? And you want to show only mybranch revert log? If it's the situation, you can use `git log mybranch --grep='revert'` to find it.

Comment: even `git log mybranch --grep='revert'` is showing reverts from all the other branches

Comment: You can compare by this way: 1. Show all revert log, `git log --grep='revert' --oneline --all`. 2. Show revert log only for mybranch, use `git checkout mybranch` and `git log --grep='revert' --oneline` or `git log mybranch --grep='revert' --oneline`. You will find the output is different by setp1 and setp2.